# Convert string of digits to integer

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write this function in Haskell called atoi, which takes a string of digits representing an integer to the integer itself.

For example, `atoi "123"` should give 123.

Here's my implementation so far:

```
atoi :: String -> Int
atoi str = show str :: Int
```

I got an error stating

> Couldn't match type

Comment: `show` converts another type to a string. To go the other way, you want `read`.

Comment: If you're doing this for homework presumably you're meant to write the conversion yourself by hand, rather than just using the existing `read` function.

Comment: What is the type of `show`? Compare that with the type of `atoi <somestring>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `read`:

```
atoi :: String -> Int
atoi s = read s :: Int
```

Example:

```
Prelude> atoi s = read s :: Int
Prelude> atoi "12345"
12345
```

Comment: Do you need the `:: Int` here in the first code block? The type signature should already constrain the output type.

Comment: Im not sure of that, I usually type it to clarify.

Comment: @Netwave You don't; explicitly typing `atoi` lets the type checker infer which instance of `Read` to use.

Comment: Using `TypeApplications`, you could also simply write `atoi = read @Int`.